# Code Error in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

While Executing the Trigger:

```
set<decimal> offerLevels = new Set<decimal>();
Set<Id> pricebookIds = new Set<Id>();
set<string> productgroups = new set<string>();
set<string> ordertypes = new set<string>();

Map<String, List<order>> offerRuleMap = new Map<String, List<order>>();

List<Order> orders = [SELECT Id, Status, Pricebook2Id, Order_Qty_Multiplier__c, (SELECT Id,Pricebook__c FROM Order_Pricebooks__r), (SELECT OrderId,Product_Group__c,OrderType__c FROM OrderItems) FROM Order WHERE Id IN (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItem WHERE Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet())];
 for(Order ord :orders){

   for(Orderitem ord2:ord.OrderItems){

    offerLevels.add(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c);

    pricebookIds.add(ord.Pricebook2Id);

    productgroups.add(ord2.Product_Group__c);

    ordertypes.add(ord2.OrderType__c);

   if(!offerRuleMap.containsKey(orders.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c + orders.Pricebook2__c + ord2.Product_Group__c + ord2.Type__c))
```

Last Line it is showing Error:

> Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a
>   concrete SObject: List Order,

How to Rectify the Error

Comment: This line: `orders.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c + orders.Pricebook2__c + ord2.Product_Group__c + ord2.Type__c`. You are accessing individual fields with List object. I guess it should be like this: `ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c + ord.Pricebook2__c + ord2.Product_Group__c + ord2.Type__c`

Comment: After changing that Compile Error: Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the error description, you are trying to access fields of an sObject using an instance of type `List` which is causing the issue.

Update your `if` condition as in below. You were using the list instance(`orders`) itself earlier.

```
if(!offerRuleMap.containsKey(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c + ord.Pricebook2__c + ord2.Product_Group__c + ord2.Type__c))
```

Comment: After changing Error: Compile Error: Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments at

Comment: This might be due to different field types. Try adding `String.valueof(yourField)` for fields which are not type of `String` e.g. `String.valueof(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c)`

Comment: Glad it helps you!

Comment: `Order_Pricebooks__c` is a child of `Order` where you can have multiple `Order_Pricebooks__c` per `Order`. So the way you are trying to access it is not correct. You have to iterate over the children list. btw, it seems this is a different question from the original post